# How to reference secondary indexes in serverless.yml?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm very unclear on how references or variables work with CloudFormation.

Currently my iAmRole in my serverless.yml looks like:

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      # Restrict our IAM role permissions to
      # the specific table for the stage
      Resource:
        - "Fn::GetAtt": [ ReportsTable, Arn ]
```

ReportsTable is a table created in another file that looks like:

```
Resources:
  ReportsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
    ...
    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: typeId-accessToken-index
          KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: typeId
            KeyType: HASH
            ...etc
```

I understand that the second value in the Fn::GetAtt array is referencing an attributename, but I don't understand where Arn is coming from. It seems like a variable but it's not defined anywhere.

Ultimately I need to add another Effect, Action, Resource block referencing the local secondary index I have created, but I'm lost as to where to start.

Edit: Looks like Arn comes from dynamoDB tables return values (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html)

Edit2: Okay so I now have the format `arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/index/*` from the [permissions reference docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html), testing now.

Comment: arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/index/* is the correct reference.

Now I need to figure out how to dynamically refer to the tablename like is being done above. And probably how to refer to my account id and region without hardcoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Cloudformation intrinsic function [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to create index arn

```
!Sub '${ReportsTable.Arn}/index/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

After referring to these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html)

and these: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html

I was able to figure out that the required format for referencing an index table is `arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/index/*`.

Further, in order to not hard code all the values in (in my case because I have several staging environments) you can do a join like so:

```
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          -
            - 'arn:aws:dynamodb:'
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - ':'
            - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - ':table/'
            - ${self:custom.tableName}/
            - 'index/*'
```

Where table name is defined in your custom block.

Comment: FYI, unless you're doing manipulation on the Join components, or importing them, you can generally use a Sub instead of a Join, which makes things easier to read: `!Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${self:custom.tableName}/index/*`